# what is the best C++ alternative to python dictionary and zip?

Tags: python, c++, dictionary

What is the best C++ alternative to dict(zip(values...)) in python?

I'm tutoring a C++ student currently in my off time, and came across a piece of Python code at my work and found I did not know the best answer.

The code looks like the following (I changed the names of variables, and generalized it a bit, but it's the same idea):

```
(dict(zip(wordCollection, [word.strip() for word in currentLine.split(',')][1:-1])))
```

I've replaced the stripped, and split words with a trimmed, tokenized vector using boost and that works fine; however I came to a loss when trying to decide the best way to translate the dict/zip combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be trying to translate idioms directly from one language to another.

In C++, you generally don't write functions that take iterators and generate new iterators; instead, you write functions that take input and output iterators and copy from one to the other. So, you could write a `zip` function that take an input iterator over `T`, an input iterator over `U`, and an output iterator over `pair<T, U>`.

But then you're not going to chain the two calls together this way, because your `zip` function isn't going to be returning anything (like an iterator range) that could be usefully passed to any kind of `dict` function. Instead, you might create a `dict` analog (an `unordered_map`), create an output iterator into that, and use a `zip` function to copy pairs into it.

Something like this:

```
template <I1, I2, O>
void zip(I1 it1, I1 it1end, I2 it2, I2 it2end, O o) {
    while ((it1 != it1end) && (it2 != it2end)) {
        *o++ = std::make_pair(*it1++, *it2++);
    }
}

std::unordered_map<T, U> mapping;
zip(c1.begin(), c1.end(), c2.begin(), c2.end(), std::inserter(mapping, mapping.end()));
```

Except I don't think you can actually use `inserter` on an `unordered_map` this way or not, so you've have to write a `map_inserter` function instead.

If you don't know the types `T` and `U` locally, you may want to wrap this all up in a function template that extracts the types from the element types of the iterators so you can `auto` it. (In C++11, you can `decltype` it without needing a function, but the expression will be a mess.)

---

If you have multiple uses for `zip` and `map_inserter`, it may be worth writing them. But otherwise, a better solution would be to expand it into an explicit loop:

```
auto it1 = c1.begin(), it1end = c1.end(), it2 = c2.begin(), it2end = c2.end();
std::unordered_map<T, U> mapping;
while ((it1 != it1end) && (it2 != it2end)) {
    mapping[*it1++] = *it2++;
}
```

Comment: true, I wouldn't normally do that directly in practice, I believe heavily in not translating idioms directly as well; I was just curious what was the best and proper "C++ way" to solve the same problem

Comment: I would write zip very differently. I'd want it to be container-like, so that the usage could be like `for (auto pr : zip(c1, c2)) { ... }`. I think that's much more usable than the OutputIterator-style of algorithms.

Comment: @Barry: I agree that such things are more useful, but they don't really fit the STL algorithm idiom. (BTW, I'm not defending the STL algorithm idiom. I loved it until I discovered things like lazy lists and Python generators in other languages, and noticed that instead of being able to use those algorithms every once in a while when it's worth writing a lot of scaffolding, you can use them all the time trivially… Which is one of the reasons I don't use C++ as much as I used to.

Comment: @abarnert that's not a trend that c++ preaches, quite the contrary, viewing how good c++ coders like Sean Parent preaches about never forgetting about the algorithms in the standard library and beyond, I have a rather different view.

Answer (score 4):

Well once you have your vectors like:

```
std::vector<std::string> wordCollection;
std::vector<std::string> splitWords;
```

then you can just iterate:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> dict; // or std::unordered_map
std::size_t minSize = std::min(wordCollection.size(), splitWords.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i != minSize; ++i) {
    dict.insert(std::make_pair(wordCollection[i], splitWords[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best C++ alternative for `dict` is `std::unordered_map`, which is a hash table, and for `zip`, it's `ranges::view::zip` from [D4128 ranges proposal](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html), for which reference implementation can be accessed at [github.com/ericniebler/range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

C++11 code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using ranges::view::zip;

    int ints[] = {1, 2, 3};
    vector<string> strings = {"a", "b"};
    unordered_map<int, string> dict(zip(ints, strings));
}
```

I hope for this to turn up as C++ standard in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(zip(labels,values))  --->  dict([("a",1),("b",0)]) ---> dict(a=1,b=0)
```

a dict is simply a hashtable ... and this is simply making a hash table of labels and values, where the labels (or keys) are `wordCollection` and the tokenized string is the values

so probably a hashtable ... although it will probably take more than one line to do it in c++